# How to preview page media, as paged media, within an iframe within a browser window

Tags: iframe, css-paged-media

Is there any way to preview page media, as paged media, within an iframe within a browser window.

(I mean any way short of converting the page to a PDF and loading it that way.)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the perfect answer if you want to preview as page media **only** the page within some specific iframe.

But if you could live with previewing the entire page while still maintaining editability, you can try [Print Edit extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/print-edit/) for Firefox.
I would start my search here—maybe you could rewrite the extension to only display the specific iframe as paged media.

---

*Disclaimer: I am not the author of the extension.*